# What is the default value that Python chooses when adding two variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

Suppose we have the following context:

```
x = 3  
y = 4  
z = x + y
```

Will `z` be an `int` or `float`, etc? I am well aware that floating numbers do end with `.something`, however its unclear to me whether Python will favour the floating point type over the integer type, given the circumstances that it is unpredictable whether the user is going to change this variable to another type or not.

Comment: Guys thank you for your both wonderful and informative answers, im wish i could rate up your answers but i have too few reputation pointes to be able to do that. I am giving the best answer to the person who answered me first. Again i cannt thank you enough guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When *mixing* types, you'll always get the 'wider' type, where a complex number is wider than float, which in turn is wider than an integer. When both values are the same type (so *not* mixing types), you will just get that one type as the result.

From the [*Numeric Types* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

> Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the “narrower” type is widened to that of the other, where plain integer is narrower than long integer is narrower than floating point is narrower than complex. Comparisons between numbers of mixed type use the same rule.

So when you are summing numbers of different types, Python will widen the narrower type to be the same as the wider type. For an operation with an integer and a floating point number, you'll get a float, as float is wider.

However, there is no point in changing the type if both operands are the same type. Changing the type in that case would be very surprising.

Comment: if i understood you correctly python will choose in this case the type int, however itll be flexible for future changes, is that so?

Comment: @Leowahyd: if both values are `int`, no coercion will take place, you get the same type again and you'll have `int`.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
>>> type(3 + 4)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(3.0 + 4)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(3.0 + 4.0)
<class 'float'>
```

If the difference between a float or integer is important to your application, explicitly convert the user input into a float so you know what you are dealing with every time.

```
user_input = float(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to test. By default, if you perform arithmetic on two integers, Python will store the result as an integer. You can see that here.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> z = x + y
>>> type(z)
<class 'int'>
```

The type function will tell you what the 'type' of an object is in Python. Here we can see that the type of the z variable is int, which stands for integer.

If we were to perform arithmetic on two different types, say integer and float, and the result was a decimal, then the result will be stored as a float.

```
>>> x = 2.55
>>> y = 3
>>> z = x / 3
>>> type(z)
<class 'float'>
```

Now, if you were to perform arithmetic on an integer and a float and the result were to come out as a non-decimal, Python will STILL store this as a float. You can see that here.

```
>>> x = 2.5
>>> y = 1.25
>>> z = x / y
>>> type(z)
<class 'float'>
>>> print(z)
2.0
```

In conclusion, when you do arithmetic, Python will store the result as an integer only if the two numbers involved were also integer. If one was float, then the new variable will also be of float type (or class).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The *mixing* rules Martijn described are a good way to think about built in numeric types. More broadly, any object can support arithmetic operators such as `+` and `*` as long as the methods are implemented. With objects `a` and `b` when you apply an arithmetic operation like `a + b` python will call `a.__add__(b)`. If that function returns `NotImplemented` then python will fall back on `b.__radd__(a)`. Using this approach it is possible for only one of the two objects to know how to work with the other, and choose to act like the *wider* type.

For example the work for `4.0 + 3` is done by the float, and `3 + 4.0` is *also* computed by the float. To make your own numeric type that in some sense *wider* than a built in you all you need to do is implement your own `__add__` and `__radd`__ methods that returns your wider type. This relies on the builtins returning `NotImplemented` for an object they don't recognize.